How to find annotations through JDI?
I have to inspect the heap of 2 different running java apps and I need to find instances with a certain annotation. Using JDI I can connect to the host JVM, I can access all the loaded classes and interfaces and I can see the annotations among the loaded classes (as interfaces). But I cannot determine which classes are annotated. If I add a normal interface, it appears as implemented in the mirrored class objects but and not the annotations.
Hoping for help here!
